# Semaphores in a recursive loop, in F#

Tags: f#

I have many threads running the same recursive loop with different parameters.

Since the loop does download files from an AWS service and writes data to a database, I do some throttling with semaphores.

A simple version would be:

```
let rec doStuffAsync a b c =
    async {        
        // wait before I can run
        executionSemaphores.WaitOne() |> ignore

        // do some stuff

        // multiples paths out
        if a then
            ...
            executionSemaphores.Release() |> ignore
            return! doStuffAsync a b c

        elif b then
            ...
            executionSemaphores.Release() |> ignore
            return! doStuffAsync a b c

        else
            ...
            executionSemaphores.Release() |> ignore
            return! doStuffAsync a b c
    }
```

The issue here is that each exit branch has its own *executionSmaphores.Release()* call.

How could I restructure this to avoid the duplication? The best I can think about is to do a WaitOne before the first loop and Release then WaitOne right at the loop entrance.

Or, is there a better way?

Comment: I don't see a loop in the code as written. I assume `doStuff` and `doStuffAsync` are actually intended to be the same function?

Comment: @BrianBerns, yes, I made a mistake. I fixed the question now

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps just refactor the common code into a function (called `loop` below), and then call that function at each exit point:

```ml
let executionSemaphores = new System.Threading.Semaphore(1, 1)

let rec doStuffAsync a b c =

    let loop a b c =
        async {
            executionSemaphores.Release() |> ignore
            if a || b || c then
                return! doStuffAsync a b c
        }

    async {
        // wait before I can run
        executionSemaphores.WaitOne() |> ignore

        // do some stuff
        printfn "%A %A %A" a b c

        // multiples paths out
        if a then return! loop false b c
        elif b then return! loop a false c
        else return! loop a b false
    }

doStuffAsync true true true
    |> Async.RunSynchronously
```

Output is:

```
true true true
false true true
false false true
```

Note that I also made some changes to prevent the code from looping infinitely.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to use language support for `IDisposable` which works more reliable in case of exceptions.

First, we need an `IDisposable` which will release semaphore

```ml
type SemaphoreReleaser(semaphore: SemaphoreSlim) =
    interface IDisposable with
       member _.Dispose() = semaphore.Release()

// and extension method for convenience

type SemaphoreSlim with
    member s.Enter() =
          s.Wait()
          SemaphoreReleaser(s)
```

Then it can be used with `use _ = s.Enter()` or `using (s.Enter()) (fun _ -> ...)`

Now let's look at code. From given sample, it looks like an infinite loop, so let's refactor it from recursion

```ml
let doStuffAsync a b c =
    async {
        while true do
            use _ = executionSemaphores.Enter()

            if a then
                ...
            elif b then
                ...
            else
                ...
    }
```

Advantage is that you won't need to add call to `Release`, it will be automatically released even if exception occurred

Comment: The sample *is* an infinite loop because that's the scenario here; each thread runs that infinite loop. 
I like the IDisposable idea a lot, but would the IDisposable function be called in case of a recursive loop?

Comment: `Dispose` will be called at end of scope. With `while`, semaphore will be released after each iteration. With original code, it will be disposed after all `if-else` and will cause deadlock. In my opinion loop is cleaner than recursion is this case